# Given a $f$, find all polynomials preserved by its induced transformation

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Recently, I've stumbled upon the following problem:

Take $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and consider this set of transformations on $\mathbb{R}^2$ induced by $f$

$$P = \{ \rho_k : (x,y) \rightarrow (x+k, y - f(k))\}$$

Is it possible to find $r(x,y)$ such that $r(\rho_k(x,y)) = r(x,y) \quad \forall x,y,k$  ?

Comment: It strongly depends on who $f$ is. If $f$ is *linear* $r(x,y)$ certainly exists.

Comment: What if $f$ is polynomial (lets say of degree 2 for example) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is always possible. You can define $r$ to be a constant function. Then your condition is trivially fulfilled.